# A multi-page Matlab code in Lyx

Tags: lyx, code

I recommend using **matlab-prettifier**
package (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/586), which only provides a style for the listing package. This will give you a good highlighting of Matlab code.

So, when I did that, I found that my PdF is not showing the whole Matlab code on one page (page1) because my code is too long, that's why the next page (page2) is blank and my other code shows on the next page (page 3).

[image]

My question is how can this long code appear on the next pages?
I mean I want such as the following image:

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Okey @Bot.  I edit my question.

Comment: With a simple example I can not reproduce the issue. Please add a compilable code from `\documentclass{` to `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thanks!  I used the special paste with the code provided by Mark Pace.  It worked perfectly!

Comment: I know where the problem is now it's because I put the program listing into the box